# Disable all desktop notifications, without exception on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, notifications

I'm working on a build of Windows 10 for a very specific deployment. Going through the sysprep / image process etc..

I've noticed that even after disabling a load of notification options in the registry, you still get these random 'fly-in' notifications about certain features. 
For example, I got one just now which advised that WiFi Sense required my attention.... despite me disabling Wifi Sense in the registry as part of the build.

Is there a definitive list of registry keys or options which relate to desktop notifications? Or can anyone add to my list below?

running build 10240

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"TaskbarNoNotification"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"TaskbarNoNotification"=-

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"EnableBalloonTips"=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"EnableBalloonTips"=-

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications]
"NoToastApplicationNotification"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer]
"DisableNotificationCenter"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell]
"UseActionCenterExperience"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WcmSvc\wifinetworkmanager]
"WiFiSenseCredShared"=dword:00000000
"WiFiSenseOpen"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: I assume you are using build 10240?  If you are not you should indicate what build you are using.

Comment: Maybe there's another set of registry settings? I found [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/223503/how-to-use-and-configure-the-new-notification-center-in-windows-10/) that shows a list of notification options in the GUI. That's useless, but it made me think that there's a duplicate of those keys in another folder of the registry that also control them.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just enable "Quiet hours"? Perhaps you could toggle that and diff the registry to see what changed?

Comment: @BenRichards looks like i'll be putting on procmon and wading through reg keys :) thanks

Comment: Hey @Damo, did you ever put together a more comprehensive list of keys? I'm interested in doing something similar.

Comment: @jgoldschrafe yes, a few more. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I compiled a list which worked for me after a lot of investigation work.

There are other manual steps I needed to do for my specific project which I don't think are relevant.

```
    Remove the Console lock display off timeout

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7]
        "Attributes"=dword:00000002

    Notifications

    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
    "TaskbarNoNotification"=dword:00000001

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
    "TaskbarNoNotification"=-

    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
    "EnableBalloonTips"=-

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
    "EnableBalloonTips"=-

    Toast

    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications]
    "NoToastApplicationNotification"=dword:00000001

    Action Centre

    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer]
    "DisableNotificationCenter"=dword:00000001

    Hero Paper

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System]
    "DisableLogonBackgroundImage"=dword:00000001


    Immersive Shell
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell]
    "UseActionCenterExperience"=dword:00000000

    LUA
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
    "EnableLUA"=dword:00000000

    Updates

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
    "NoAutoUpdate"=dword:00000001

    WiFi Sense

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WcmSvc\wifinetworkmanager]
    "WiFiSenseCredShared"=dword:00000000
    "WiFiSenseOpen"=dword:00000000

    No Lock Screen

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization]
    "NoLockScreen"=dword:00000001

    Quiet Mode

    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings]
    "NOC_GLOBAL_SETTING_TOASTS_ENABLED"=dword:00000000
```